# Is SKStoreReviewController helpful in writing a review?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I implemented `SKStoreReviewController`. It gave a prompt to rate the app.
If I click on the stars, it is showing two buttons titled **Submit** and **Cancel**. My app is still not in the App Store, so the Submit button is disabled.

I want to know what happens when Submit is clicked after my app was uploaded to the App Store. Will the rating be submitted directly or does it redirect to the App Store to write a review?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Submit button of the prompt of [`requestReview()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) will redirect you to the **Write a Review** page of the app, with the stars section already filled out. You can optionally enter a title and a detailed review there. (The description text is misleading, the title **is** optional.)

From [the Ratings, Reviews, and Responses - App Store page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/) of Apple Developer:

> Users will submit a rating through the standardized prompt, and can authenticate with Touch ID **to write and submit a review**.

[image: "Write a Review" page with filled out stars]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. You just used requestReview method from SKStoreReviewController. Am I right???

Comment: @ManikantaHanumansetti Yes, my answer applies for the prompt that appears after `requestReview()` is called.

Comment: @the4kman, After tapping on 'Submit', will it directly take the user to 'Write a Review' page on AppStore or user has to tap on any other things extra? when will this screen with 'Write a Review' option on an alert comes?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n5xlg5t8jzli54h/763AC80B-A9E8-4BB6-B399-79C8854F8A83.jpg?dl=0

Comment: is there any option to filll title and review section in the url?

Comment: @mehdi No, that's not permitted by Apple.